# Revalidate on-demand a Next.js site from Django model's save method

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, next.js

I have a next.js site deployed to Vercel, that fetches data from an API provided by Django. Next.js has this new feature (Incremental Static Regeneration On-Demand) where you can rebuild a specific page without need to rebuild the entire site with an url like this:

https://<my-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=my-token

I need the next.js site rebuild some pages when the database changes, so it shows the new data, and i tried to make a request (with requests package) in the save method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    r = requests.get("https://<my-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=<my-token>")
```

It seems to work when i trigger that url from my browser, but it doesn't work when i trigger it from Django. The response of this Response object (r) is a 200 Status Code, as expected, with {"revalidated":true} (r.text), but it doesn't update the site anyways.

How can i implement this?

**EDIT:** here's the pages/api/revalidate.js code:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {  
    if (req.query.secret !== process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
    }
    try {
        await res.unstable_revalidate('/')
        await res.unstable_revalidate('/url')
        return res.json({ revalidated: true })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
    }
}
```

Comment: _"It seems to work when it trigger that url from my browser, but it doesn't work when i trigger it from Django."_ - can you clarify what you mean by this? After making the request to the API route from the Django backend, does the page not get updated when you reload the page on your website?

Comment: Exactly. If i enter https://<my-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=<my-token> from my web browser, chrome or brave, the page refresh it's content. But when i make the request from the Django backend (on database change), the page doesn't refresh it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. I think it wasn't working because you actually need to save before revalidation.

This worked for me:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        r = requests.get("https://<my-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=<my-token>")
```